# Prove that no two distinct paths obtained by "rotating $\pi_0$" clockwise by a multiple of $\pi/k$ share an edge

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Let $P_0,\cdots, P_{2k}$ be vertices of a complete graph. Let $\pi_0 := (P_0,P_1,P_2,P_{2k}, P_3, P_{2k-1},\cdots, P_{k+2},P_{k+1},P_0)$ be the vertices of a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph. Prove that no two distinct paths obtained by "rotating $\pi_0$" clockwise by a multiple of $\pi/k$ share an edge (rotating $\pi_0$ $p \pi/k$ radians corresponds to replacing each vertex $P_i$ of $\pi_0$ by $P_{i+p},$ where indices are treated modulo $2k$).

Let $\pi_p$ denote $\pi$ rotated $p\pi/k$ radians clockwise.

I thought of finding a general formula for the ith vertex of $\pi_0$ and getting a contradiction if the paths share an edge, but I wasn't able to come up with one. Alternatively, one might be able to prove that any such path is uniquely determined by a single edge. However proving this formally seems to require knowing some more formal formula for the ith vertex of $\pi_0$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\pi_0 := (P_0, P_1, P_{2k}, P_2, P_{2k-1}, \cdots, P_{k+2}, P_{k+1}, P_0)$? The way the problem is currently stated, $\pi_0$ and its rotation by $\pi / k$ shares the edge $(P_1, P_2)$.

Comment: The correct version of this construction should actually have one vertex (say, $P_0$) be "special", and only cycle the indices of $P_1, \dots, P_{2k}$. The diagram in which "rotation by $\pi/k$" makes sense places $P_1, \dots, P_{2k}$ at the vertices of a regular $(2k)$-gon, and $P_0$ at its center. I would recommend looking at that diagram to solve this problem: there, one can see a clearer rule for which edges are part of $\pi_p$.

Comment: Do you mean a decomposition like [this one](https://proofits.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/nora_hartsfield_gerhard_ringel_pearls_in_graph.pdf) (see Thm. 2.3.1 on p. 38)? In there, except for the edges incident with special vertex, the remaining path splits into $2$ matchings, where matched vertices in one add up to $-1\,\text{mod}\,2k$ and $0\,\text{mod}\,2k$. Here we assume that the $2$ singleton vertices in one of the matchings are matched to themselves. This is probably the invariant you are looking for.